# define on const int, but put the value in the installed header

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ library which does some numerical work. The main parameter is the number of segments. For speed it matters a factor 3 that the number of segment is `const`, however I would like to define it at compile time using `-DSEGMENTS 32`. The header looks like this:

```
#ifdef SEGMENTS
const int segments = SEGMENTS
#else
const int segments = 20
#endif
```

That works. However, programs linking with this library don't get the `-DSEGMENTS` and thus `segments` is always 20. Without the `const` I know the solution, but with I don't know. I can imagine some `extern` trick or installing the header after precompiling if that is possible with cmake.

Comment: If the header isn't getting the number of segments, then your problem is: how do i pass the number of segments ?

Comment: I believe C and C++ are different in their treatment of `const`. Tag changed to reflect the text of your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the other libraries to take the value externally you should declare it as external in the header:

```
extern const int segments;
```

You define it in one code file (.cpp) like you describe above:

```
#ifdef SEGMENTS
const int segments = SEGMENTS
#else
const int segments = 20
#endif
```